# VB.net Save File Dialogue error - Could not find special directory 'Desktop'

Tags: vb.net

I have a fairly straight forward peice of code that just tries to set the default saved directory for a standard .net save dialogue to a specific folder.  If that folder doesn't exist, it sets it to the desktop.

This works fine for everyone but one user who is getting the following error:

```
Could not find special directory 'Desktop'
```

How is that even possible?

```
        'Check if folder exists
        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(strDirectory) Then
            strDirectory = FileIO.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
            If Not IO.Directory.Exists(strDirectory) Then
                strDirectory = IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
            End If
        End If


    'Show save file dialogue.
    Dim folderDlg As New Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
    folderDlg.SelectedPath = strDirectory
    folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = True
```

Comment: is their language something other than English?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
strDirectory = _
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop).ToString()
```

I use [GetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx) to get "My Documents" and it works fine (I don't ever have to think about it).